# Error with a non int object put as "Int object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, pygame

I am using pygame to make a snake game, and I have 2 variables `x` and `y` which I am trying to define. I have it as the following:

```
def drawSnake(snakeCoords):
    for coord in snakeCoords:
        x = coord["x"] * CellSize
        y = coord['x'] * CellSize
        snake_segmentRect = pygame.draw.rect(x, y, CellSize, CellSize)
    pygame.draw.rect(displaysurf, green, snake_segmentRect)
    snake_segmentInnerRect = pygame.Rect(x + 4, y + 4, CellSize - 8, CellSize - 8)
    pygame.draw.rect(displaysurf, green, snake_segmentInnerRect)
```

...and get the error:

```
line 175, in drawSnake
x = coord['x'] * CellSize
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Please help, the other similar questions are not helpful at all.

Comment: what is `snakeCoords`? Apprently, it is returning `ints` as you iterate over it, and then you try to index those: `coord['x']*CellSize`, what do you *expect* to happen? You need to provide a *reproducible example* of you issue, including code that will reproduce the error, as well as your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the value of snakeCoords coming into that function is a list of ints.

Put a print statement to make sure:

```
def drawSnake(snakeCoords):
    for coord in snakeCoords:
        print(type(coord))
        x = coord["x"] * CellSize
        y = coord['x'] * CellSize
```

You should see the following output python2:

`<class 'int'>`

or this in python3:

`<object 'int'>`

That is causing your error.

Comment: This would better serve as a comment: this is information needed in the actual question.

Comment: Yes, that was what I got however, is it a possibility to allow it to be an integer? It would fit the purpose of my code.

Comment: @Icedart It looks like you need to pass in a list of dictionary objects that have x and y keys (the y key is not written in your code). If all wanted was an x and y coordinate then using a tuple might be better. You would have to rewrite your function to handle that.